# Move post title inside the featured image in a site homepage

Tags: css

I'm trying to edit my homepage (https://robadapixel.it/)
I have edited some code to remove useless things, moved some object and changed some "hard coded" color.
Now i need to edit a widget, i'd like to show the post title inside the featured image and not below like it's now.

basically i want to edit that ONLY the big article in the "LaunchBox" section looks like the slide on top page.

I have forced all the "side article" (named following-post) to mantain the same background and position by editing style.css file and made this code to move the "article-content" zone inside the image but  when i stretch the screen the title expand under the image showing a weird white section (the single-article clearfix background) this things don't happens in the top slider and the title remain inside of the pic.

```
.widget_featured_posts .article-content {
position: relative;
top: -60px;
padding: 10px 15px 7px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

I looked around in the code and i didn't understand how the "single-article clearfix" section are resized and how to make it the same size of the image... any idea?

Maybe i have writed a lot of bullshit but i'm not a programmer, i'm simply trying to understand how it works...

Comment: So after some try, the height of "single-article clearfix" is always equal to Image sixe + article content size, even if i shift it with top: -60px command.
It's fault of the Cleafix suffiss? forcing the heght of the clarfix obj it's not a good idea since it not resize when i shrink the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the image height happens because you have specified the `width` and `height` explicitly. You can remove both attributes and update the CSS for the `.wp-post-image` inside `.single-article` to have

```
height: 100%;
```

Then, after the image is expanding to the height of the `.following-post`, you can move the title inside the container with the image by changing its position to `absolute`:

```
.article-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And finally, in order to position the title according to the image container, add `position: relative` to the `.single-article`.

Notice that the CSS selectors I have used are only meant to point you to the right elements. You need to update the CSS by using more specific selectors, in order to avoid styles of other elements getting messy.

Comment: It works! thank you so much!
I did not undertand very well about the first line (the thumbnail size are automatically created by the theme, i don't have specified any other parameters) but following your other suggestion i was able to fix my problem.

Comment: Hey, just to make sure the point from the first line is clear, I'm talking about the `<img width="555" height="333" src="..." class="attachment-colormag-featured-post-medium..." title="Aggiungere giochi...">` element. But as you say, they may be set by the theme.